# Initializing with a Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, initialization

I'm trying to initialize the following returned json into an object (environment), but I can't figure out how to assign the sub-hash (i.e. settings) part.

```
{"deploymentEnvironmentId" => 54321,


"accountId" => 1234,
  "provider" => "Agent",
  "name" => 'test',
  "settings" =>
        { "providerSettings" =>
        [{
        "name" => "test_setting",
        "value" => {
          "isEncrypted" =>false,
          "value" => "myaccount"
    }
    }]
  }
}
```

I've tried adding a public send style init method, but it is not pulling back the provider section when querying

`@environment.settings[provider_settings].first[name]`

```
class Environment
    def initialize(options = {})
        if options
            options.each { |k,v| public_send("#{k}=",v)}
        end
    end
    def id
        @deploymentEnvironmentId
    end
    def settings(settings = {})
      options.settings.each { |k,v| public_send("#{k}=",v)}
    end
    attr_accessor :deploymentEnvironmentId
    attr_accessor :accountId
    attr_accessor :name
    attr_accessor :provider
    attr_accessor :projectsMode
    attr_accessor :created
    attr_accessor :updated
    attr_accessor :settings
end
```

Answer (score 1):

SO I was accessing the inner array incorrectly. With a bit of help from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707363/initializing-with-a-hash) and IRB.

Accessing it as `@environment.settings['providerSettings'].first['name'])` works a treat.

I'm sticking with the variables passed back from the json as whilst they urk me not following convention right now, it *does* work.

Thanks @maicher for pointing out that I was setting, then overriding `@settings`

Answer (score 0):

You defined `settings` method and then, by calling `attr_accessor :settings` it has been overwritten.

Probabbly you have a bug in `options.settings.each` line. I think it should call the `settings` from method's argument.

You can try fixing that, but there can be more bugs.

Instead trying to fix that, I'd suggest to set all the options explicitly.

```
class Environment
  class Error < StandardError; end

  def initialize(options = {})
    self.deployment_environment_id = options.fetch('deploymentEnvironmentId')
    self.account_id = options.fetch('accountId')
    # ...
    self.name = options.fetch('settings').fetch('providerSettings').first.fetch('name')
    # ...
  rescue KeyError => e
    raise Error, "Options hash is invalid. #{e}"
  end

  def id
    deployment_environment_id
  end

  attr_accessor :deployment_environment_id
  attr_accessor :account_id
  attr_accessor :name
  attr_accessor :provider
  attr_accessor :projects_mode
end
```

What we can see here?

- attributes are set expicitly.
- attributes' names follow ruby convention for naming (snake case).
- using fetch instead of `[]` is making the initialization fail (by raising `KeyError`) on invalid hash, so it gives you an assurance that you will not end up with an object halfly initialized.
- `KeyError` can be rescued to specify custom error message.

Maybe it's not exactly what you've asked for, but I believe that this approach will make that code more readable for other developers and for you in the future.